# Adding a link to each stacked bar chart item

Tags: javascript, highcharts, sharepoint-2013

I have a stacked bar chart I am trying to make each item in the chart that is clicked open the sharepoint view based on what was clicked.

I am building the data here

```
seriesData.push({ name: xStatus[i], data: dataArray, url: countArray[i].url });
```

my chart code looks like this:

```
loadStackedBarChartWithLink = function (xCategories, seriesData, divId, chartTitle, yAxisTitle) {
    //Build Stacked Bar Chart
    $(divId).highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: chartTitle
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: xCategories,
            allowDecimals: false
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            allowDecimals: false,
            title: {
                text: yAxisTitle
            }
        },
        legend: {
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            reversed: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                stacking: 'normal',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            location.href = this.options.url;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: seriesData            
    });
}
```

The chart has the correct data, pointer is correct but I get 'undefined' for the url.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
IWSChartBuilder.PersonEngagementsByStatusChart = function () {
var load = function () {
    $.when(            
        IWSChartBuilder.RESTQuery.execute(GET THE DATA HERE)
    ).done(
        function (engagements1) {
            var data = [];
            var countArray = [];
            var urls = [];

            var results = engagements1.d.results;                
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                if (results[i].Consultant.Title == undefined) {
                    continue;
                }
                var found = false;
                for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                    if (data[j].personName == results[i].Consultant.Title && data[j].statusName == results[i].Engagement_x0020_Status) {
                        data[j].statusCount = data[j].statusCount + 1;
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!found) {                        
                    data.push(new IWSChartBuilder.StatusByPerson(results[i].Consultant.Title, results[i].Engagement_x0020_Status, 1));

                }
            }

            //Put data into format for stacked bar chart
            var seriesData = [];
            var xCategories = [];
            var xStatus = [];
            var i, j, cat, stat;

            //Get Categories (Person Name)
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                cat = data[i].personName;
                if (xCategories.indexOf(cat) === -1) {
                    xCategories[xCategories.length] = cat;
                }
            }
            //Get Status values
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                stat = data[i].statusName;
                if (xStatus.indexOf(stat) === -1) {
                    xStatus[xStatus.length] = stat;
                }
            }

            //Create initial series data with 0 values
            for (i = 0; i < xStatus.length; i++) {
                var dataArray = [];
                for (j = 0; j < xCategories.length; j++) {
                    dataArray.push(0);
                }
                seriesData.push({ name: xStatus[i], data: dataArray });
          }

            //Cycle through data to assign counts to the proper location in the series data
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var personIndex = xCategories.indexOf(data[i].personName);
                for (j = 0; j < seriesData.length; j++) {
                    if(seriesData[j].name == data[i].statusName){
                        seriesData[j].data[personIndex] = data[i].statusCount;                            
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            //Build Chart
            IWSChartBuilder.Utilities.loadStackedBarChartWithLink(xCategories, seriesData, "#engagementsByStatusChart", "Engagements by Status", "Total Projects");     
        }
    ).fail(
        function (engagements1) {
            $("#engagementsByStatusChart").html("<strong>An error has occurred.</strong>");
        }
    );
};

return {
    load: load
}
```

}();

The way I am trying now

```
plotOptions: {
            series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                stacking: 'normal',
                point: {
                    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            getURL(this, xCategories, seriesData);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },

function getURL(chartInfo, xCategories, seriesData) {

var baseUrl = "correctURL" + xCategories[chartInfo._i] + "-FilterField2%3DEngagement%255Fx0020% 255FStatus-FilterValue2%3D" + chartInfo.name;
location.href = baseUrl;
```

}

Comment: Are you sure countArray[i].url is valid ?

Comment: What does your seriesData look like? Can you do a `console.log(seriesData)` and see what the `url` element is?

Comment: I had to fix the url.  Compared it to what the actual view has and now they match.  Still get Undefined

Answer (score 1):

You are hooking into the point click event handler. In this handler, 'this' refers to the point, not the series.

Try this:

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            stacking: 'normal',
            events: {
                    click: function () {
                        location.href = this.options.url;
                    }
            }                
        }
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2DG84/

If you need URL's which depend on point values as well as the series, you can access both. e.g.

```
plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            stacking: 'normal',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function () {
                        alert(this.series.options.url + "&y=" + this.y);         
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

In this example, there is a base URL on the series, by I am adding to the UTL with the point.y value.

http://jsfiddle.net/Fygg2/

Comment: Updated. It should this.options.url.

Comment: Ok now I am at least getting a view, but it doesn't pertain to the item on the chart.  I have other charts working fine but this stacked one is making me lose more hair .. thoughts?  If the bar isn't stacked it appears to be working.

Comment: I was adding the URL to the y axis items (didn't show the stacked part).  Didn't work.  I now have the url's in another VAR which I am passing to the chart code.  How do I make that link use the new var I am passing in?

Comment: I put this in the chart code but doesn't work:    events: {
                        click: function () {
                            location.href = data.viewUrl;
                        }
                    }

Comment: I created a 1 dim array with the urls and with the location.href it puts them all together with ,'s

Comment: I don't really understand what isn't working for you. Maybe you need to post some more of your code. Did the look at the fiddle I posted which showed it working for a stacked chart based on your original code ?

Comment: Solution provided by SteveP is exactly answer for your question. He shows you how to add redirect for url for whole series when clicked. Be more specific what doesn't work for you. `seriesData.push({ name: xStatus[i], data: dataArray, url: countArray[i].url });` - if you want another variable, just use there it..

Comment: The first 2 variables passed in are the Y and X axis respectively.  The stacked chart could have a bar that has multiple items.  Neither of those would work because they don't directly relate to the actual bar.  For Y axis I have say John and Joe, X axis I have active and complete.  If there is a active and complete on Joes bar I need to provide the link for that bar that equates to how many Joe has active.  So if Joe had 2 actives, when I click on that bar it should display the 2 active items for Joe.  Here is more code:

Comment: It sounds like you want a diffent URL for each point, not each series. This is possible as you can hook into the point event (like in your original code). You can generate a different URL for each point in your series data.

Comment: @SteveP yes I need a url for each point.  I appreciate your patience as I have no clue (yet) what I am doing.

Comment: So you need to use objects as points like: data:[{x:0,y:1,url:'http://www.google.com'},{x:1,y:2,url:'http://tempurl.com'}];

Comment: Where do I do this?  Do I need to redo the code?  This was given to me before they wanted to add the url's.  keep in mind also, I really don't know what I am doing (no JS, Sharept or Highcharts experience).

Comment: I've added an example of using point info. If you tell us what format you need the URLs in, we can help some moer.

Comment: I have the urls built with no issues.  I can pass them into the chart code if needed.  I am also now toying with making the urls in the chart code (chart code calls a function) but I cant figure how to get the right index for xCategories on a stacked one.

Comment: As I think I have mentioned, the y axis only has 2 labels, x has 2 also.  Is there anyway to get the correct index (top to bottom where top is 0)?  the way I am trying to get working now is on the chart code and if I can get the correct index then I should have it working

Comment: chartInfo = this
xCategories = John, Joe
seriesData = Active, Complete

I could have 1 bar that has for joe 1 active and 5 completes.

Comment: I finally figured it out.  To get the first value I used xCategories[chartInfo.x], 2nd value - chartInfo.series.name